# Acceptance rejection bound

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, sampling, monte-carlo

I want to use acceptance rejection to sample from a certain PDF $f(x)$. I was able to upper bound the PDF by
$$ f(x) < h(x) = d x^c \exp(-a(x-b)^2)$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are positive constants.
As per the acceptance rejection algorithm, I want to know if $h$ can be linked to a known PDF or even better can it be upper bounded by a known PDF.

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakagami_distribution Since the kernel looks like the square root of gamma distribution (shifted), so you may refer to this distribution. I assume you are taking the positive real as the support.

Comment: I'm considering the positive real line. However, the problem is that I have a shifted term only in the exponential and not in the power which make a bit difficult to match it with the Nakagami-m PDF.